# Python readline reading incorrect \n

Tags: python, hex, newline

I am trying to process a bunch of files; my test set is 50 files; 47 of the files work fine but 3 of the files have a weird issues. Once this is working I can process the few thousand other files.

I am trying to create a more useful set of files; by default the files are named with a number based on when they are created; the "pretty" name is in the first line; it is bracketed by a bunch of hex which for my purposes is useless; the beginning of the name is always at 0x80 and character following the end of the name is always 0x00

```
with open(i, 'rb') as f:
    firstline = f.readline()
    #print(str(firstline))
    posBegin=128
    posEnd=firstline.find(hexNameEnd.encode(),posBegin + 1)
```

In one of the files; printing firstline gives;

```
 ...x19\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x19\x01\x00\x00\n
```

But looking at the file in a hex editor shows only 0A in this position; how do I force it to look only for windows line endings; 0D 0A? Adding newline='\r\n' doesn't work.

Comment: newline controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to text mode).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so obviously I am now feeling dumb; my issue is that I was using readline() rather then read()

```
with open(i, 'rb') as f:
    firstline = f.read(200)
    #print(str(firstline))
    posBegin=128
    posEnd=firstline.find(hexNameEnd.encode(),posBegin + 1)
```

Since the name is always at 0x80; and the names are never any longer then approx 30 characters; reading the first 200 bytes is all I needed to do. Grab my data from there. Even if I get some really long names they should easily fit within the read bytes.